# How to reverse only the characters(Leaving numbers) in a word in a sentence?

Tags: java

The characters in a sentence should be reversed and not the words

I have tried the below code

```
public class ReverseWords {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ReverseWords obj = new ReverseWords();
    obj.reverseWordInMyString("It Costs 25000rs for 1 LCD Projector");
    obj.reverseWordInMyString("8990.33 ");
}
public void reverseWordInMyString(String str)
   {
    String[] words = str.split(" ");
    String reversedString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
        {
           String word = words[i]; 
           String reverseWord = "";
           boolean numeric = true;
           try {
               Double num = Double.parseDouble(word);
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
               numeric = false;
           }
           if(!numeric) {
           for (int j = word.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) 
       {

        reverseWord = reverseWord + word.charAt(j);
       }
       reversedString = reversedString + reverseWord + " ";
        }
           else {
           reversedString = reversedString + word + " ";
           }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(reversedString);
   }
```

}

The output which I am getting is : tI stsoC sr00052 rof 1 DCL rotcejorP

The Expected output is :tI stsoC 25000sr rof 1 DCL rotcejorP

Comment: I'm certain I saw this question a few days ago

Comment: `NumberFormatException` is going to be thrown on 25000sr because it is not a double. Seems like you might need to loop through the word and find substrings that only contain number chars.

Comment: What if you had **23a23b23**?  would it change to **23b23a23** or stay the same?

Comment: @JeevaD: Why do you check for numeric? Just treat everything as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class ReverseWords { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "It Costs 25000rs for 1 LCD Projector";
        String output = Arrays.stream(a.split(" "))
            .map(s -> s.matches(".*\\d.*") ? reverseWithNumbers(s) : reverse(s))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
        System.out.println(output);
    }

    public static String reverseWithNumbers(String input) {
        return Arrays.stream(input.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"))
            .map(s -> s.matches(".*\\d.*") ? s : reverse(s))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
    }

    public static String reverse(String input) {
        return new StringBuilder().append(input).reverse().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `25000rs -> 25000sr`.

Comment: give me a second:)

Comment: At this point I think it would be simpler to just go char-by-char)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```
      String str = "It Costs 25000rs for 1 LCD Projector";
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]+)").matcher(str);
      StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
      while (m.find()) {
         String rev = temp.append(m.group(1)).reverse().toString();
         sb.replace(m.start(), m.end(), rev);
         temp.setLength(0);
      }
      String reversed = sb.toString();
      System.out.println(reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't like this solution, since I don't like while-loops in general, but it seems to be the cleanest way to do this char-by-char (please tell me how it can be improved). It also should be the most efficient solution. I understood the problem as "sequences of alphabetical chars should be reversed".

```
public class ReverseWords {
  private static void reverse(char[] a, int left, int right) {
    right --;
    while (left < right) {
      char temp = a[left];
      a[left] = a[right];
      a[right] = temp;
      left++;
      right--;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] a = "It Costs 25000rs for 1 LCD Projector".toCharArray();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < a.length) {
      if (!Character.isAlphabetic(a[i])) {
        i++;
        continue;
      }
      int j = i + 1;
      while (j < a.length && Character.isAlphabetic(a[j])) {
        j++;
      }
      reverse(a, i, j);
      i = j;
    }
    System.out.println(new String(a));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

How about using regex? Matching on something like `[a-zA-Z]*[^(\d*)]` will isolate your Alpha characters without matching with your digits. Depending on the requirements of the project, that statement may have to be modified slightly, but should get you on the right track.